# Express router not mounting

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am doing my 1st project using expressjs and I am having a problem with a router not mounting.  I basically have app mounting a router object which then is supposed to mount a second router object.  The 1st embedded router is mounted successfully by the app.use command but the second layer embedded router is not being mounted by the 1st layer embedded router.  I need someone smarter than me to tell me why my approach is not working.  All help is much appreciated.

See project details and code snippets below.
[image]

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//path to db controller and model scripts
app.set('dbPath','/db');
//build connect string
var host='localhost'
var port='27017';
var dbName = 'Reckon_Orbs';
app.set('dbConnectString','mongodb://'+host+':'+port+'/'+dbName);
var dbRouterMod = require('./routes/db/db_router.js');
var dbRouterContainer = new dbRouterMod(express,app.get('dbPath'),app.get('dbConnectString'));
app.use('/db', dbRouterContainer.dbRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

db_router.js

```
var DbRouter = function(express,dbPath,connectString) {
    this.dbRouter = express.Router();
    var userRouterMod = require('./user_router.js');
    var userRouterContainer = new userRouterMod(express,dbPath,connectString);
    //this.dbRouter.get('/user',function(req,res){res.send("hello")});
    this.dbRouter.use('/user',userRouterContainer.userRouter);
    console.log("db_router instantiated");
};

module.exports = DbRouter;
```

user_router.js

```
var UserRouter = function(express,dbPath,connectString){
    this.userRouter = express.Router();
    this.userRouter.get('/get',function(req,res){res.send("hello")});
    console.log("user_router instantiated");
};

module.exports = UserRouter;
```

When I start node using node www, I get the following output which suggests my classes are being instantiated.

```
C:\NETSHARE\data\devprojects\eclipse\Reckon_Orbs\bin>node www
user_router instantiated
db_router instantiated
Express server listening on port 3000
```

The result that I get when I call: `http://localhost:3000/db/user/get` is a 404 error.  However, if I uncomment out the commented line of code in db_router and call `http://localhost:3000/db/user`, I get "hello" as a response.  This suggests that the mounting of the 1st layer embedded router works fine.

Comment: In addition to using the class approach listed above where you get a reference to the class and then use new to instantiate, and then access the router as a property, I also tried exporting a normal function rather than a constructor and then having the function explicitly return the router. And then using the returned router in the mount. This produced identical results.  The db router mounts property but the user router does not.

Comment: I wonder if the problem is that you can't mount to a router that isn't mounted to the app root.  In my examples, user router is attempting to mount to the db router before the db router is mounted to the app router.  I will test this and provide results.

Answer (score 1):

Let me help you with how you can organise it nicely and make everything work.

You can have **app.js** something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var config = require('./config/config');
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// view engine setup, it can be ejs, jade or whatever you like
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

var connect = function(){
   var options = {
      server: {
         socketOptions:{
            keepAlive : 1
         }
      }
   };
   mongoose.connect(config.db,options);
};
connect();
mongoose.connection.on('error',console.log);
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected',connect);


require('./config/routes')(app);  
require('./config/express')(app);
module.exports = app;
```

**config/config.js**

```
//you can further break your configuration for different environments such as development, production, test, stating etc.
var path = require("path");
var extend = require("util")._extend;

var development = require("./env/development");
var test = require("./env/test");
var production = require("./env/production");

var defaults = {
   root: path.normalize(__dirname + '/..')
};

module.exports = {
   development: extend(development,defaults),
   test: extend(test,defaults),
   production: extend(production,defaults)
}[process.env.NODE_ENV || "development"]
```

**config/env/development.js**

```
module.exports = {
    db: 'mongodb://localhost/MeanDemo_dev'
};
```

Very neatly you can organize your routes.

**config/routes.js**

```
var routes = require('../routes/index');
var users = require('../routes/users');
module.exports = function (app){
      app.use('/', routes);
      app.use('/user',users);
}
```

example of routes, which calls the controller which eventually interacts with MongoDB in my case.
**routes/index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var meetupController = require('../app/controllers/MeetupController');

router.post('/meetup',meetupController.create);
router.get('/meetup',meetupController.getAll);
router.get('/meetup/:id',meetupController.get);
router.put('/meetup/:id',meetupController.update);
router.delete('/meetup/:id',meetupController.delete);
module.exports = router;
```

My project skeleton looks like:
[image]

You can take a look at full source code [here](https://github.com/narendrasoni1989/mean-demo), it's a nice example if you further want to have Angularjs in front end.
So this is how i organize my code and it works just fine. I hope it will help you too. Thanks.

Comment: You have provided me an elegant solution to structuring a project.   That is helpful for someone like myself who is new to the technology. However, what I was really looking for was an answer to why my embedded router isn't mounting.  From what I read of the express documentation, I should be able to mount multiple layers of routers if needed and I want to understand how that works.  If you can tell me how to do that, I will mark this as answered.

Comment: Expressjs is highly configurable,there are many ways to structure project. If you can understand the underlying connect middleware concept in Express, then you can easily figure out. Solution what i gave you was to correct your project structure to avoid the problems that you was facing. If you still want your project to be cluttered and un-manageable then it's your choice. I don't see any reason of passing db config as parameter to dbRouterMod(..), similarly you can even add a controller layer to your routes, so these are some of the suggestions from myside. happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem.  You cannot mount router A to a router B if router B isn't already mounted.  So instead of building router modules bottom up in the route path, you must build them top down starting at the app.  I modified my code to look like the following and it works as expected.  Note that my solution is to include a function that mounts a router's sub routers after the router has been mounted.  So the caller has to mount the new router and then call the router's executeMount function to mount any routers further down the mount chain.   This solution allows for dependency injection during router creation which is what I was looking for.

app.js

```
var dbRouterMod = require('./routes/db/db_router.js');
var dbRouterContainer = new dbRouterMod(express,app.get('dbPath'),app.get('dbConnectString'));
app.use('/db', dbRouterContainer.router);
dbRouterContainer.executeMounts();
```

db_router.js

```
var DbRouter = function(express,dbPath,connectString) {
    this.router = express.Router();
    console.log("db_router instantiated");
    this.executeMounts = function(){
        var userRouterMod = require('./user_router.js');
        var userRouterContainer = new userRouterMod(express,dbPath,connectString);
        this.router.use('/user',userRouterContainer.router);
        userRouterContainer.executeMounts();
    };
};

module.exports = DbRouter;
```

user_router.js

```
var UserRouter = function(express,dbPath,connectString){
    this.router = express.Router();
    console.log("user_router instantiated");    
    this.executeMounts = function(){
        this.router.get('/get',function(req,res){res.send("hello")});
    };
};
module.exports = UserRouter;
```